# further separating / calling function that is in class from object

Tags: java, function, class, static, inner-classes

I'm having trouble calling `move.m_north` from another function.

It is asking me to make the class `move` and the function `m_north` static, but if I do i can't reference `y` unless I make it static too.

I found that if `y` is static then any `dot` object I make will have the same value for `y`, and I need multiple `dot`s

```
public class dot {
     int y=0; //<-- 3. but if I make this static then it will stay the same for every object
     public void step(int direction) {
          switch (direction){
               case 0:
                    move.m_north(); //<-- 1. is asking to make move.m_north static
          }

     }
     public class move {
          public int m_north() {
               if (y > 0) {
                    y -= 1; //<-- 2. but I need to modify and read non static variables
                    return -1;
               } else return -2;
          }
     }
}
```

I am able to call `m_north` if it is not in the `move` class but there are many similar functions which I believe need to be split up so I can use same names and it becomes easier to find different functions.

I would much appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about why you want `m_north` to be in a `move` class? It seems like it would be simpler to make it a method on `dot`. This might also be clearer if you stick with standard Java naming conventions. Using lowercase names for classes makes them look like variables (and you may need to add a variable to store an instance of the `move` class)

Comment: because there are very many methods in dot with similar naming, I need to break it up.

Comment: Could you please explain the variable class thing further. Will it still be able to access `dot`s `y` with many objects. Is there another way of using the m_north method by move.m_north() without the use of a class?

Comment: You could have `case 0:  new move().m_north(); `. That would fix the compile error, but I somehow doubt that is what you want.

Comment: Off-topic: If the directions are limited, such as North, East, South, West, and possibly NE, SE, SW, NW, I would use an `enum` for directions.

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer What do you mean? I have to call it from many other methods as well.

Comment: How many methods do you mean? More than just the four directions? What other kinds of methods? Having several methods with similar names is not itself a reason to introduce a class here.

Comment: around 30-40 methods every 8th may need a similar name

Comment: Breaking it up is not necessarily a viable solution here.  You may have to keep it together -- but find other ways to consolidate things, like representing directions as values instead of using different methods.

Comment: Oracle's [enum tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

Comment: @LouisWasserman could you Explain further

Comment: I suspect the O/P has some code design issues. But, discussing them here is outside the scope of this question. It could be an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: I`ll try enums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make this work by declaring an instance of the move class. For example (with captialization changed to match Java naming conventions):

```
public class Dot {
     int y=0;
     Move move = new Move();

     public void step(int direction) {
          switch (direction){
               case 0:
                    move.m_north();
          }

     }
     public class Move {
          public int m_north() {
               if (y > 0) {
                    y -= 1;
                    return -1;
               } else return -2;
          }
     }
}
```

Note that `Move` with an uppercase `M` is the class name, and `move` with a lowercase `m` is the name of an instance variable in the class `Dot`.

The reason this is required is that `m_north` requires an *enclosing instance* of `Dot` in order to access its `y` field. To put it another way, you need to call `m_north` on a specific dot's move instance. Making the method static doesn't provide an enclosing dot in scope.